# Stuff With XML Path

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
select @v =STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN MeterID=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MeterID) + ',' END AS [text()] 
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mr.MeterID FROM #FilteredMeterIDs mr WHERE mr.apartmentID = fmr.apartmentID)m
                        FOR XML PATH,TYPE).value('(.)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'')
                    FROM #FilteredMeterIDs fmr
select @v
```

**Result:**
181834,

BUT when i use below query , it gives NULL as RESULT,

```
DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
select @v =STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(MeterID,0)=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MeterID) + ',' END AS [text()] 
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mr.MeterID FROM #FilteredMeterIDs mr WHERE mr.apartmentID = fmr.apartmentID)m
                        FOR XML PATH,TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'')
                    FROM #FilteredMeterIDs fmr
select @v
```

**Result:**
NULL

i have used "/text()" for improving performance. What is the issue, can anyone tell me ?!

Comment: Can you provide sample data? The most likely issue is you're not specifying the path for the text() call. See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42730b77a7028f844a3e5dd3995d1eb8) for an example.

Comment: i have tried  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'). and got the expected solution.